# Error: Variable auxi is already defined in method main (String[])

Tags: java

sigo con mis estudios de programación y se a generado un problema en mi codigo, me indica que la variable **auxi** ya se encuentra definida en un metodo, pero la *intento* usar para invocar el arrayList, lo curioso es que no me arrojo ese error con las variables anteriores, que las use de la misma forma.

tambien supongo que por este error es que tambien me genera un error en la linea `Bus bs = new Bus(Patente, Capacidad, CiudadSalida, CiudadDestino, HoraSalida, tChofer, tAzafata, tAuxiliar);`

Les estaria muy agradecido si me corrigen en lo que estoy equivocado

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;



public class ParteI {
    private static TipoLicencia TL;
    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    static ArrayList<Cliente> Client = new ArrayList<>();
    static ArrayList<Chofer> Driver = new ArrayList<>();
    static ArrayList<Azafata> Azaf = new ArrayList<>(); 
    static ArrayList<Auxiliar> Auxil = new ArrayList<>();
    static ArrayList<Bus> Buus = new ArrayList<>();
    static String Bsc;

public static void main(String[] args) {


    boolean salir = false;
    int opcion, Edad, Capacidad;
    String Rut, Nombre, Apellido, Telefono, Telefono_E, Patente, CiudadSalida, CiudadDestino, HoraSalida;
    Chofer tChofer;
    Azafata tAzafata;
    Auxiliar tAuxiliar;

    while(!salir) {      


        System.out.println("Menu Opciones");
        System.out.println("[1] Agregar");
        System.out.println("[2] Buscar");
        System.out.println("[3] Reserva");
        System.out.println("[4] Ver");
        System.out.println("[5] Salir");

        try{



            System.out.println("=== Ingrese Numero de Opcion ===");
            opcion=sc.nextInt();

            switch (opcion){
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("Eliga que desea A G R E G A R");
                    System.out.println("[1] Cliente");
                    System.out.println("[2] Chofer");
                    System.out.println("[3] Azafata");
                    System.out.println("[4] Auxiliar");
                    System.out.println("[5] Bus");
                    opcion=sc.nextInt();
                    switch (opcion){
                        case 1://------------------------------------------- Agregar Cliente
                            System.out.println("Agregar un CLIENTE");
                            String Correo;
                            System.out.println("Rut: ");
                            Rut = sc.next();
                            System.out.println("Nombre: ");
                            Nombre = sc.next();
                            System.out.println("Apellido: ");
                            Apellido = sc.next();
                            System.out.println("Telefono: ");
                            Telefono = sc.next();
                            System.out.println("Correo: ");
                            Correo = sc.next();

                            Cliente clie = new Cliente(Correo, Rut, Nombre, Apellido, Telefono);
                            Client.add(clie);

                            break;

                        case 2://------------------------------------------- Agregar Chofer ########################
                            System.out.println("Agregar Chofer");
                            System.out.println("Seleccione tipo de licencia");
                            System.out.println("[1] A1");
                            System.out.println("[2] A2");
                            System.out.println("[3] A3");
                            System.out.println("[4] A4");
                            System.out.println("[5] A5");
                            System.out.println("[6] B");
                            System.out.println("[7] C");
                            System.out.println("[8] D");
                            System.out.println("[9] E");
                            System.out.println("[10] F");
                            opcion=sc.nextInt();
                            if (opcion == 2){
                                System.out.println("Rut: ");
                                Rut = sc.next();
                                System.out.println("Nombre: ");
                                Nombre = sc.next();
                                System.out.println("Apellido: ");
                                Apellido = sc.next();
                                System.out.println("Telefono: ");
                                Telefono = sc.next();

                                Chofer cho = new Chofer(TipoLicencia.A2, Rut, Nombre, Apellido, Telefono);
                                Driver.add(cho);
                            }else{
                                System.out.println("Lo sentimos, no requerimos un Chofer con este tipo de Licencia");
                            }

                            break;

                        case 3://------------------------------------------- Agregar Azafata
                            System.out.println("Agregar Azafata");
                            System.out.println("Edad");
                            Edad = sc.nextInt();
                            if (Edad >= 21){
                                System.out.println("Rut: ");
                                Rut = sc.next();
                                System.out.println("Nombre: ");
                                Nombre = sc.next();
                                System.out.println("Apellido: ");
                                Apellido = sc.next();
                                System.out.println("Telefono: ");
                                Telefono = sc.next();

                                Azafata azafa = new Azafata(Edad, Rut, Nombre, Apellido, Telefono);
                                Azaf.add(azafa);
                            }else{
                                System.out.println("Lo sentimos, necesitamos alguien mayor a 21 años");
                            }

                            break;

                        case 4://------------------------------------------- Agregar Auxiliar
                            System.out.println("Agregar Auxiliar");
                            System.out.println("Rut: ");
                            Rut = sc.next();
                            System.out.println("Nombre: ");
                            Nombre = sc.next();
                            System.out.println("Apellido: ");
                            Apellido = sc.next();
                            System.out.println("Telefono: ");
                            Telefono = sc.next();
                            System.out.println("Telefono Emergencia: ");
                            Telefono_E = sc.next();

                            Auxiliar auxi = new Auxiliar(Telefono_E, Rut, Nombre, Apellido, Telefono);
                            Auxil.add(auxi);

                            break;

                        case 5://------------------------------------------- Agregar BUS #####################################################################################
                            System.out.println("Agregar Bus");
                            System.out.println("Capacidad");
                            Capacidad = sc.nextInt();
                            System.out.println("Patente");
                            Patente = sc.next();                                
                            System.out.println("Ciudad de Salida");
                            CiudadSalida = sc.next();
                            System.out.println("Ciudad de Destino");
                            CiudadDestino = sc.next();
                            System.out.println("Hora de Salida");
                            HoraSalida = sc.next();

                            for(Chofer cho : Driver){
                                System.out.println("Seleccione C H O F E R");
                                System.out.println("Ingrese R U T que desea B U S C A R");
                                Bsc = sc.next();
                                if(Bsc.equals(cho.getRut()));{
                                    System.out.println("RUT Encontrado");
                                    tChofer = cho;
                                    }
                                }

                            for(Azafata azafa : Azaf){
                                System.out.println("Seleccione A Z A F A T A");
                                System.out.println("Ingrese R U T que desea B U S C A R");
                                Bsc = sc.next();
                                if(Bsc.equals(azafa.getRut()));{
                                    System.out.println("RUT Encontrado");
                                    tAzafata = azafa;
                                    }
                                }

                            for (Auxiliar auxi : Auxil){ //Aqui es donde se genera el error <------------------------
                                System.out.println("Seleccione A U X I L I A R");
                                System.out.println("Ingrese R U T que desea B U S C A R");
                                Bsc = sc.next();
                                if(Bsc.equals(auxi.getRut()));{
                                    System.out.println("RUT Encontrado");
                                    tAuxiliar = auxi;
                                    }
                                }


                            Bus bs = new Bus(Patente, Capacidad, CiudadSalida, CiudadDestino, HoraSalida, tChofer, tAzafata, tAuxiliar);
                            Buus.add(bs);

                            break;

                        default:
                            System.out.println("Opcion no valida");

                    }//Fin switch2
                    break;

                case 2:
                    System.out.println("Eliga que desea B U S C A R");
                    System.out.println("[1] Cliente");
                    System.out.println("[2] Chofer");
                    System.out.println("[3] Azafata");
                    System.out.println("[4] Auxiliar");
                    System.out.println("[5] Bus");
                    opcion=sc.nextInt();
                    switch (opcion){
                        case 1:
                            System.out.println("Ingrese R U T que desea B U S C A R");
                            Bsc = sc.next();
                            for(Cliente clie : Client){
                                if(Bsc.equals(clie.getRut()));{
                                System.out.println("RUT Encontrado");
                                System.out.println("Nombre: " + clie.getNombre() + " Apellido: " + clie.getApellido() + " Correo: " + clie.getCorreo());
                                }
                            }
                            break;

                        case 2:
                            System.out.println("Ingrese R U T que desea B U S C A R");
                            Bsc = sc.next();
                            for(Chofer cho : Driver){
                                if(Bsc.equals(cho.getRut()));{
                                System.out.println("RUT Encontrado");
                                System.out.println("Nombre: " + cho.getNombre() + " Apellido: " + cho.getApellido() + " Tipo Licencia: " + cho.getLicencia());
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            System.out.println("Ingrese R U T que desea B U S C A R");
                            Bsc = sc.next();
                            for(Azafata azafa : Azaf){
                                if(Bsc.equals(azafa.getRut()));{
                                System.out.println("RUT Encontrado");
                                System.out.println("Nombre: " + azafa.getNombre() + " Apellido: " + azafa.getApellido() + " Edad: " + azafa.getEdad());
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            System.out.println("Ingrese R U T que desea B U S C A R");
                            Bsc = sc.next();
                            for(Auxiliar auxi : Auxil){
                                if(Bsc.equals(auxi.getRut()));{
                                System.out.println("RUT Encontrado");
                                System.out.println("Nombre: " + auxi.getNombre() + " Apellido: " + auxi.getApellido() + " Telefono Emergencia: " + auxi.getTelefono_E());
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                        case 5:

                            break;
                        default:
                            System.out.println("Opcion no valida");    
                    }
                    break;

                case 3:
                    System.out.println("Reserva");
                    break;

                case 4:
                    System.out.println("Eliga que desea V E R");
                    System.out.println("[1] Cliente");
                    System.out.println("[2] Chofer");
                    System.out.println("[3] Azafata");
                    System.out.println("[4] Auxiliar");
                    System.out.println("[5] Bus");
                    opcion=sc.nextInt();
                    switch (opcion){
                        case 1:
                            System.out.println("C L I E N T E");
                            for(Cliente clie : Client)
                                System.out.println("Nombre: " + clie.getNombre() + " Apellido: " + clie.getApellido() + " Rut: " + clie.getRut() + " Correo: " + clie.getCorreo());
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            System.out.println("C H O F E R");
                            for(Chofer cho : Driver)
                                System.out.println("Nombre: " + cho.getNombre() + " Apellido: " + cho.getApellido() + " Rut: " + cho.getRut() + " Tipo Licencia: " + cho.getLicencia());
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            System.out.println("A Z A F A T A");
                            for(Azafata azafa : Azaf)
                                System.out.println("Nombre: " + azafa.getNombre() + " Apellido: " + azafa.getApellido() + " Rut: " + azafa.getRut() + " Edad: " + azafa.getEdad());
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            System.out.println("A U X I L I A R");
                            for(Auxiliar auxi : Auxil)
                                System.out.println("Nombre: " + auxi.getNombre() + " Apellido: " + auxi.getApellido() + " Rut: " + auxi.getRut() + " Edad: " + auxi.getTelefono_E());
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            System.out.println("B U S");
                            break;
                        default:
                            System.out.println("Opcion no valida");    
                    }
                    break;

                case 5:
                    System.out.println("Usted a decidido salir1");
                    salir = true;
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Opcion debe ser entre 1 y 5");

        }// Fin switch

        }catch(InputMismatchException e){
            System.out.println("Debes introducir un numero");
            sc.next();
        }



    }//fin while


    System.out.println("Fin del menu"); 



}
```

}

Comment: Sugerencia: trata de dividir tu código en métodos más pequeños. Es mas legible y te va a ayudar evitar este tipo de error.

Comment: Mas o menos en la linea 140 cambia `Auxiliar auxi = new Auxiliar(Telefono_E, Rut, Nombre, Apellido, Telefono);
                            Auxil.add(auxi);` la variable **auxi** por otro nombre.

Comment: Uno de los **problemas** es que para el for estás usando una variable ya declarada para la lectura de lo que hay en ¿`Auxil`?, o sea en esta línea: `for (Auxiliar auxi : Auxil){...` Con esto debería funcionar, si no hay otros errores en tu código: `for (Auxiliar itemAuxi : Auxil){`, luego, dentro del `for` todo lo que haga referencia a `auxi` debería cambiar a `itemAuxi`, por ejemplo: `itemAuxi.getRut()`. Aunque es un código muy extraño, porque veo que dentro del for haces asignaciones a `auxi`, porque lees filas siguientes del scanner, etc. No sé qué resultado inesperado que podría tener eso.

Comment: Gracias por sus consejos, efectivamente de esa forma logre solucionar el error, veo que aun debo entender mas las cosas, e intentare ser mas ordenado y aplicar metodos. muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Separa el ámbito de cada declaracion utilizando llaves `{}` para los `case` para que reconozca la declaracion de manera independiente:

```
int b = 4;
switch(b)
{
   case 1:{
     int a = 444;
   }
   break;
   case 2:{
      int a = 555;
   }
   break;
 }
```

El error que muestra es debido a que el alcance de las variables corresponde al `switch`, no a los `case`. En otras palabras: lo que declares en el switch, sera una declaracion general para los `case`, aunque no posible acceder a las variables declaradas de en los case anteriores.